# How can I get acess token with msal in my python script

Tags: python, authorization, ms-office, azure-ad-msal, onenote

I'm trying to download OneNote notebooks using python, and then automating the workflows with github actions.

I've already tried with [onenote export](https://github.com/Danmou/onenote_export) repository, however I found out that I can't automate this project while hosting the redirect server.

Anyways, I'm currently working on below script. I found out hte code from [here](https://blog.darrenjrobinson.com/microsoft-graph-using-msal-with-python/).

```py
import msal
import jwt
import json 
import requests 
import pandas as pd 
from datetime import datetime
import yaml

with open('config.yaml') as f:
    config = yaml.safe_load(f)
f.close()
scopes = ['Notes.Read', 'Notes.Read.All']

accessToken = None 
requestHeaders = None 
tokenExpiry = None 
queryResults = None 
graphURI = 'https://graph.microsoft.com'

def msgraph_auth():
    global accessToken
    global requestHeaders
    global tokenExpiry
    tenantID = config['tenant_id']
    authority = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' + config['tenant_id']
    clientID = config['client_id']
    clientSecret = config['secret']
    scope = ['Notes.Read', 'Notes.Read.All']

    app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(clientID, authority=authority, client_credential = clientSecret)

    try:
        accessToken = app.acquire_token_silent(scope, account=None)
        print('accessToken', accessToken)
        if not accessToken:
            try:
                accessToken = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=scope)
                if accessToken['access_token']:
                    print('New access token retreived....')
                    requestHeaders = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken['access_token']}
                else:
                    print('Error aquiring authorization token. Check your tenantID, clientID and clientSecret.')
            except:
                pass 
        else:
            print('Token retreived from MSAL Cache....')

        decodedAccessToken = jwt.decode(accessToken['access_token'], verify=False)
        accessTokenFormatted = json.dumps(decodedAccessToken, indent=2)
        print('Decoded Access Token')
        print(accessTokenFormatted)

        # Token Expiry
        tokenExpiry = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(decodedAccessToken['exp']))
        print('Token Expires at: ' + str(tokenExpiry))
        return
    except Exception as err:
        print(err)

def msgraph_request(resource,requestHeaders):
    # Request
    results = requests.get(resource, headers=requestHeaders).json()
    return results


# Auth
msgraph_auth()

# Query
queryResults = msgraph_request(graphURI +'/v1.0/users',requestHeaders)

# Results to Dataframe
try:
    df = pd.read_json(json.dumps(queryResults['value']))
    # set ID column as index
    df = df.set_index('id')
    print(str(df['displayName'] + " " + df['mail']))

except:
    print(json.dumps(queryResults, indent=2))
```

This is the result of above script.

"access token is empty."

```json
{
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
    "message": "Access token is empty.",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2022-07-20T11:24:50",
      "request-id": "0aa38753-50be-40f8-9ba9-a5036b153c05",
      "client-request-id": "0aa38753-50be-40f8-9ba9-a5036b153c05"
    }
  }
}
```

I'm pretty sure that Tenant_id, client_id, scopes, and secret key that I configured are right.

I think the problem is that

```py
app.aquire_token_for_client()
```

above code was failed to acquire token, but I don't know how can I acquire token with other ways.

Was the code wrong? or, are there other ways to acquire token with msal?
Thank you!